# Strange behavior of ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have a Strange behavior of my ListView. First my Widget Tree so far:
I updated the Source Code so its more easie to understand.
When I add an height to my ListView like I did, it gets Scrollable but I can scroll over the empty box, so its still there....

```
Padding(
        ....
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [ Container(...),
              child: ClipRRect(
                   .....
                child: foodStream.when( //<-- Data comes from riverpod streamprovider
                    data: (food) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: food.length,

                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text("test");
                          })
```

[image]

You can see the widget in the screenshot. As you can see there, I have a huge empty box under my last "test" for no reason. After the `})` I only close my brackets, no more SizedBoxes or other widgets.
Does anybody know from where this space comes from?

Comment: The last time I checked,
`ListView` requires that it's parent has a defined height.
Perhaps you're defining that height somewhere inside `ClipRRect`

Comment: It is already to true